# how to find the standard errors of an estimated parameters

Tags: matlab

I estimated parameters by using a maximum likelihood method through the function `fminsearch`, but I don't know how to come up with the standard errors of the parameters (to compute the *p*-values).

This my model code:

```
function f = myRegime1(p,y,o)

    T   = size(y);
    x   = 0;
    xi1 = 0.8;
    xi2 = 1-xi1;
    LL  = 0;

    for t = 2:T

        k = o(t);

        p11 = exp(p(1)+p(2)*k) / (1+exp(p(1)+p(2)*k));
        p22 = exp(p(3)+p(4)*k) / (1+exp(p(3)+p(4)*k));

        s = y(t);
        f = p(5) + p(6)*o(t);

        x(t) = s-f;

        e1 = x(t)-p(7);
        e2 = x(t)-p(8);

        L1 = -log(2*pi) - log(sqrt(p( 9))) - e1^2/(2*p( 9));
        L2 = -log(2*pi) - log(sqrt(p(10))) - e2^2/(2*p(10));

        L = xi1*p11*L1 + xi1*(1-p11)*L2 + xi2*p22*L2 + xi2*(1-p22)*L1;

        xi1 = (xi1*p11*L1 + xi2*(1-p22)*L1)/L;
        xi2 = (xi1*(1-p11)*L2 + xi2*p22*L2)/L;

        LL = LL+L;
    end

    f = LL;

end
```

Comment: p-value and confidence intervals are two different things. Also getting the CI is tricky and I believe it is based on the chosen model. You may want to make the model equations more explicit, and migrate the question to cross-validated.

Comment: The p-values should suffice for my purposes. How you think I can get just them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would refer you to [this discussion on matlabcentral](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/157530) which seems to address your question. The basic idea seems to be to find a numeric estimate of your standard deviation and Jacobian, and then calculate your standard error from there. The code given is fairly well documented.

Comment: I think the documents you mentioned is confusing, Could you explain it better?